# Using Python regex find and replace to add HTML tags around raw text

Tags: python, regex

I'm building a simple web app using Flask and I want to know if it is possible to use regex to find and replace the numbers in Fe2O3 + CO -> Fe + CO2 and surround them with the sub HTML tag so it becomes Fe<sub>2</sub>O<sub>3</sub> + CO -> Fe + CO<sub>2</sub> when displayed in HTML.

Comment: have you tried anything yet?

Answer (score 1):

Try something like this, Here `a` is your input string. Implemented without using regex.

```
In [1]: a = 'Fe2O3 + CO -> Fe + CO2'
In [2]: ''.join(['<sub>'+i+'</sub>' if i.isdigit() else i for i in a])
Out[1]: 'Fe<sub>2</sub>O<sub>3</sub> + CO -> Fe + CO<sub>2</sub>'
```

Answer (score 0):

I have a similar situation, but I wanted a regular expression that would be more robust to larger numbers and possible isotope information (in the format that is output by RDKit). Here's what I came up with:

```
def html_formula(value):
    comps = re.split('([A-Z][a-z]?|\[\d+[A-Z][a-z]?\])(\d+)', value)
    html = ''.join(['<sub>{}</sub>'.format(i) if i.isdigit() else i for i in comps])
    return html
```

For example:

```
>>> html_formula('Fe2O3 + CO -> Fe + CO2')
'Fe<sub>2</sub>O<sub>3</sub> + CO -> Fe + CO<sub>2</sub>'

>>> html_formula('C123[13C]2H456N276O351S5')
'C<sub>123</sub>[13C]<sub>2</sub>H<sub>456</sub>N<sub>276</sub>O<sub>351</sub>S<sub>5</sub>'
```

For usage in a Flask, you can define a template filter:

```
@app.template_filter('html_formula')
def html_formula(value):
    comps = re.split('([A-Z][a-z]?|\[\d+[A-Z][a-z]?\])(\d+)', value)
    html = ''.join(['<sub>{}</sub>'.format(i) if i.isdigit() else i for i in comps])
    return html
```

Then in your jinja template (remember to use `safe` to avoid html escaping):

{{ mf | html_formula | safe }}